Endless problems drawing diagrams on a windows forms app beyond the control's visible coordinates range
So I have a windows forms app in VB.NET in VS2022.
I need to draw some geometric diagrams (circles, lines, arcs, rectangles etc). I know how to do that. It's easy and not the problem.
The problem is that if I draw on an picturebox, and the diagrams reach beyond the visible limit of the picturebox, the remainder of the image gets clipped and I cannot access it.
I check if I can add a scrollbar to a picturebox. Turns out, I cannot.
So I switched the picturebox with a panel and drew on the panel. I added scrollbars to the panel like this, in the parent form's load():
Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 1000)
pnlResult.AutoScrollMinSize = rect.Size

This conveniently adds the much required scrollbars on the panel (with autoscroll turned on, of course). But now when I try and scroll down, the diagram disappears.
In order to fix that, I put all my diagram draw code in the panel's pain() event, like this:
Private Sub pnlResult_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles pnlResult.Paint
    DrawDiagrams(pnlResult, diag_array, diag_count)
End Sub

But then it started to draw over and over the already drawn diagrams as I scrolled down. In order to mitigate that, I put in the code to invalidate the panel before DrawDiagrams() as:
    pnlResult.Invalidate()
    DrawDiagrams(pnlResult, diag_array, diag_count)

But now the panel is aggressively refreshing itself, putting the entire form in a state of freeze.
What do I do?
Can't a newbie programmer get to get scrollbars on an imagebox and be done with this sort of headache?

You need BOTH a PictureBox and a Panel. Go back to a PictureBox (making sure it's big enough) and draw your diagrams on that. Now add a Panel to your Form and put the PictureBox INSIDE the Panel with the Panel's AutoScroll set to True.


In DrawDiagrams(pnlResult, diag_array, diag_count), you're not passing the e.Graphics object. So, what device context are you drawing onto? Why don't you post your code in full instead of some pieces here and there? + Note that you can also scale you're drawing. The Graphics object has specific transformations for that


Put differently, w/ respect to Jimi's comment, if you're using CreateGraphics() to draw with, that's why your drawing disappears. Definitely call your DrawDiagrams() from within the Paint() event, but pass the e.Graphics from that event into your drawing method.

You can draw based on the current scroll position, which is available through the AutoScrollPosition property of the Panel. When you scroll, the panel's position changes, so the drawing needs to shift accordingly.
Avoid excessive use of Invalidate() as it can lead to performance issues.
Draw directly on the Graphics object passed in the PaintEventArgs to manage proper scrolling behavior.
Of course as @Idle_Mind said, embedding a large enough PictureBox in a panel and adding scroll bars to the panel is a simpler solution.
